# MySQL Lag Function

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on code to get lag and lead times. I was able to succeed in getting correct lead values but, incorrect lag values. Below is the code:

```
Select t1.user_id, t1.time_period,

t1.time_period - (select t2.time_period from monthly_usage as t2
                         where t2.user_id = t1.user_id and 
                         t2.time_period < t1.time_period
                         order by t1.time_period desc LIMIT 1) as lag,
(SELECT 
            t2.time_period
        FROM
            monthly_usage as t2
        WHERE
            t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                AND t2.time_period > t1.time_period
        ORDER by t1.time_period
        LIMIT 1) AS lead

from monthly_usage as t1;
```

My output is looking like this

[image]

But I want output as below.

[image]

Is there any error in my code?

Comment: Why you are doing subtraction in `lag()` ?? try to remove `t1.time_period - ` before lag.

Comment: I have tried it removing `t1.time_period`... but this time the lag values are replaced by the number 3 in all rows.

Comment: Provide the table structure `SHOW CREATE TABLE monthly_usage` and example data as ascii data table not as images or provide a sqlfiddle.com. Also provide expected output as ascii data table based on the example data.

Comment: @user9651591.. That because you are ordering from the outer query  `t1` hence, the result would go also wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me correct your query for *lag*

```
select t1.user_id, t1.time_period,
       (select t2.time_period 
        from monthly_usage as t2
        where t2.user_id = t1.user_id and 
              t2.time_period < t1.time_period
              order by t2.time_period desc LIMIT 1) as lag, -- order by t2.time_period desc
....
from monthly_usage as t1;
```